# (New User) I've got a problem in my Ubuntu after formatting

Tags: gui, 18.10, bug-reporting

I was very happy user in Ubuntu but when this problem came

[image: This is my first big problem]

I detected that `VirtualBox` was the problem, I tried so hard to fix it but I couldn't, So I formatted my system and installed Ubuntu once again.

But now my system is **freezing** and this is annoying as I don't know how to detect the problem.
I saw some Q&A here and I tried most of them but without any benefit.

So I need help!

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1030181/400278). It may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @AlexLowe This is about virtual box but I guess it's because **Ubuntu Base** because I formatted my system and now I just got these problems

Comment: So now you have the same issues described on the question I suggested?

Comment: @AlexLowe **Yeah!**

Comment: Did you try any of the things suggested in the question? Increasing the number of CPU cores allocated to the VM for example.

Comment: @AlexLowe My system is ubuntu and my virtual was Windows, This is impossible 