# Unable to start ubuntu 18.04.2 in Virtual Box 6.0.4 on Windows 10(Desktop)

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, windows-10

I am trying to install ubuntu inside virtual box. After adding the iso file, then click on the start button it's showing below the screen. But nothing happens after that. It is the first time to setup ubuntu. So I am expecting the setup process as described [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox).

[image]

I have already tried this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030181/ubuntu-18-04-lts-freezes-while-in-boot-in-wndows-virtual-box-solution) but does not work for me.

**NB** I applied same procedure at my laptop & it worked. But fetch problem for the desktop.

Comment: Your picture shows that it is, in fact, started and running. Can you [edit] your question and explain what is not working for you?

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue or not, but you probably want to give it more than 16MB of video memory

Comment: @AndroidDev tried this but does not work for me.

Comment: I find out about my problem. For me, Hyper-V causes the problem. You need to turn off that.